# How to convert a number to string, of the form 1=A1, 2=A2, ... 9=B1, ... 64=H8 in Golang?

Tags: string, go, char, int, chess

This code is giving `A1..A9, B0..B9, C0..C9, ...`.

But I only want `A1..A8, B1..B8, C1..C8, D1..D8, E1..E8, F1..F8, G1..G8, H1..H8` (1-64).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func ToString(n int8) string {

    return string((n/10)+65) + string(((n%10)+49)-1)

}

func main() {
    var i int8
    for i = 1; i < 11; i++ {
        fmt.Println(ToString(i))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you're dividing by the wrong number. If you want the numbers only up to 8, you need to divide by 8.

Secondly, you don't need to subtract one in the second string, but you do need to decrease the `n`.

```
func ToString(n int8) string {
    n--
    return string((n/8)+65) + string((n%8)+49)
}

func main() {
    var i int8
    for i = 1; i <= 64; i++ {
        fmt.Println(ToString(i))
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BdAce3C5JL

Answer (score 3):

Let's see different approaches and performance improvements.

All the solutions and the benchmarking code can be found on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UGXfua171n). The code on the Playground is a test file, not an executable. You have to save it into a file named `XX_test.go` and run it with `go test -bench .`.

#### String concatenation

Ainar-G's answer is cool (+1):

```
func ToStringConcat(n byte) string {
    n--
    return string((n/8)+65) + string((n%8)+49)
}
```

#### Byte slice

But note that the previous solution concatenates 2 `string` values which is "costly" especially if we want to call this `ToString()` many times.

<sup>One might think that we could spare the `string` concatenation if we would try to convert a single integer number containing the 2 codes (the first shifted left by 8 bits), but that wouldn't work as converting integer numbers to `string` results in a `string` value with a single `rune` (a `string` containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer).</sup>

But we may use a `[]byte` with 2 values (the letter code and the digit code), and then we only need to [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) this single slice value to `string`:

```
func ToStringSlice(n byte) string {
    n--
    return string([]byte{(n / 8) + 65, (n % 8) + 49})
}
```

#### String constant and slicing

`string` values are [slicable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) in Go which results in a new `string` (new `string` header). So we may use a `string` constant of all the values, and do a simple slicing to get the part we need:

```
const values = "  A1A2A3A4A5A6A7A8B1B2B3B4B5B6B7B8C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8E1E2E3E4E5E6E7E8F1F2F3F4F5F6F7F8G1G2G3G4G5G6G7G8H1H2H3H4H5H6H7H8"

func ToStringConst(n byte) string {
    n *= 2
    return values[n : n+2]
}
```

#### Dictionary

Even though slicing a `string` results in a substring which shares the underlying array, it sill needs to create a new `string` header.

Since we don't have a lot of possible values, best (fastest) solution is to prepare all the possible values, and just do a simple lookup. Since input is a number, we don't even need a `map`, we can use a simple `[]string` slice:

```
var dict = []string{"",
    "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8",
    "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8",
    "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8",
    "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8",
    "E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5", "E6", "E7", "E8",
    "F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8",
    "G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5", "G6", "G7", "G8",
    "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", "H8",
}

func ToStringDict(n byte) string {
    return dict[n]
}
```

### Speed analysis (benchmark)

Let's benchmark speed of the above solutions:

```
func BenchmarkConcat(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { ToStringConcat(1) }
}

func BenchmarkSlice(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { ToStringSlice(1) }
}

func BenchmarkConst(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { ToStringConst(1) }
}

func BenchmarkDict(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ { ToStringDict(1) }
}
```

Result:

```
BenchmarkConcat-4       20000000               106 ns/op
BenchmarkSlice-4        100000000               17.0 ns/op
BenchmarkConst-4        2000000000               1.34 ns/op
BenchmarkDict-4         2000000000               1.04 ns/op
```

Just by jumping from concatenation to slice conversion, it immediately becomes **6 times faster**.

Utilizing string slicing, we again make it **12 times faster**.

And pre-building all possible values and just doing a simple lookup, we further **gain 22%**.

Comparing the final to the initial: the dictionary lookup is **a hundred times faster** than the original concatenation.

#### Using `fmt`

For completeness, here's a solution using the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package:

```
func ToStringFmt(n byte) string {
    n--
    return fmt.Sprintf("%c%c", (n/8)+65, (n%8)+49)
}
```

But this one is slower by almost 2.5 times even than our slowest String concatenation solution, as this has to wrap arguments into `interface{}` values, create and put them into a slice (for the vararg), has to parse and analyze a format `string`, use reflection to process arguments, build the `string` representation in a buffer which finally is used to produce the returned `string` value. A lot of things happen which are for the "general" case and are not required for our "special" case.

Comment: I keep being amazed by the thoroughness and the effort you put into your answers. You should write a book.

Comment: @Ainar-G And what would be its title?

Comment: If it's a tutorial book, "Gopher's First Go" sounds nice.